# Tools for Coding and Debbugging Modules of Open ERP

Tags: python, ide, odoo

I want know if some IDEs or tools exists who can help to **code** and **debug** Modules of **OpenERP 7** i tried tools of `Python` in Eclipse but it still slow and useless.
There is some powerful tools dedicated for OpenERP developers ?

Answer (score 0):

Slow and useless?  We have 4-5 devs on this platform and it works well.  Could there is a problem with your setup?  What do you mean by "tools of python" - I am using the pydev plugin.

My laptop is Win 7 but I use VirtualBox and run an Ubuntu VM with Eclipse with Pydev and postgres in the VM.  I find debugging works well and performance is pretty good allowing for the fact it is a laptop, certainly good enough for most things.  The biggest hold up is usually adding/removing columns to tables with a lot of rows as Postgres actually creates a new table in the background and copies the rows across into the new table, but this is a Postgres effect and will be the same no matter what.

There are no dedicated tools that I am aware of.  I think most people work like this but there is always pycharm or komodo or even go the pure editor way with sublime.

Comment: i'm searching for a good edi and debuggers not simple editor with text hightlighting